# Curvature of the boundary vs. normal derivative of the first eigenfunction

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, laplacian, eigenfunctions, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Let $\varphi_1$ be the first eigenfunction of the zero Dirichlet Laplacian in a planar bounded domain $\Omega$. That is,
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
-\Delta \varphi_1 &= \lambda_1 \varphi_1 &&\text{in } \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2,\\
\varphi_1 &= 0 &&\text{on } \partial \Omega.
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

If $\Omega$ has corners, and we look at the plot of $\varphi_1$, then we see that its normal derivative tends to zero near *exterior* (outward) corners, and tends to infinity near *interior* (inward) corners.

[image]

This fact suggests that, in a smooth domain, there should be some connection between *curvature* of the boundary at a point and the *normal derivative* of $\varphi_1$ at this point. 
That is, if the curvature is big positive, then the normal derivative is small. And if the curvature is big negative, then the normal derivative is large.

However, I was not able to find corresponding inequalities in the literature. 
I would appreciate some references to such facts and related results in this direction.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know about this exact problem, but you might be interested in this: https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.3709 which has a similar flavor, and it indeed depends on curvature of the boundary.